# Best pattern to display info on modal + link for more info

Tags: ios, hyperlinks, modal-windows

I am struggling in finding a good pattern for this problem, or maybe I am just overthinking.

In a mobile app, my client wants to display important privacy information for kids, willing to 'disrupt' the experience. I decided to use a modal view with some nice illustrations to provide this piece of info, and giving the user the possibility of quickly dismissing it (and not seeing it anymore). But, and this is where I have the doubts, the user needs to also have the possibility of "Learn more". This will open the browser redirecting to a in-depth help page.

Putting this "Learn More" as a button in my modal window seems wrong, as this is not really triggering an action or performing a task. But how else can include a 'link'?

Hope I was clear.
Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 1):

Richie

this is a tough dilemma
i think the learn more button is triggering an action, it may not be related to the functionality of the app but still its an affordance
hence we will need a good signifier (yes the button) to indicate this possible action.